# Viewing merged Annotations using DLIB IMGLAB

Tags: xml, dlib

I am using dlib for object detection.  Suppose, if my task is to identify cars and buses from an image, I do the object detection separately for cars and buses and I am merging the annotations.  I am trying to open the annotation xml file again to validate the object detection.

For example, if my merged xml file is masterAnnotation.xml then i would use:

```
./imglab ~/masterAnnotation.xml
```

I am able to see the boxes around relevant objects.  However the problem is the rectangle line thickness is very thin and also changes randomly for each image.  So is the size of the labels.  This renders very poor visibility of the lines and labels around the detected objects.  Is there a way to set the color of the rectangle and label fixed for all the different objects identified.

Comment: The line thickness in imglab is constant at one pixel and the colors do not vary from one image to the next.  I don't see how you could be having this experience unless you are using a modified version of imglab instead of the official version.

Comment: @DavisKing Thank you Davis King.  I am using dlib-19.4 version and have not made any modifications.  You can access an example here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ahXKBupZHjjhfLQIi2ifpBG20fYdCICp

Comment: My bad, the color doesn't change with each image, but with each different object.  It would be of immense help to me if you could guide me to keep the color constant, say green, with 2 or 3 pixel thickness.

Comment: Try the newest version of imglab.  It picks better colors now.

Comment: @DavisKing Ok thank you.  Will try.  I figured the rectangle properties are controlled by thickness, pixel_type and val....I changed thickness...but couldn't locate the origin of pixel_type and val...any way I will try the new version of imglab.  Thank you for the all the support.

Comment: You may try [web](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab) version, if it helps.

Comment: @AmitGupta  Thank you...this is very useful